# How to rename a directory in C?

Tags: c

I searched online to find that how to change the directory name? But I found nothing. All I found was `rename()` that was changing filenames. I want to change a directory name. Linux uses `mv` command for renaming a directory but if the directory contains large files then moving will take time more right? I want to do this in C.

Comment: Renaming directory is not moving the files anywhere. It is just changing a record in a filesystem.

Comment: [POSIX `rename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) renames directories. If you're on a system that does not comply with POSIX interface you may need a different (system specific) function. The C Standard does not assume directories even exist. *BTW: Linux mostly adheres to POSIX interface.*

Comment: `inux uses mv command for renaming a directory but if the directory contains large files then moving will take time more right?` It depends. If you move within the same filesystem then no. If you move between filesystems then yes.

Comment: I suppose it is vacuously true that "if a directory contains large files then moving it will take more time", but it is only true because directories do not contain files.  Therefore, it is never true that a directory contains large files.  Directories contain names, not files.  That is why they are called "directories" and not "folders".

Answer (score 3):

On every file system I can think of, renaming a directory doesn't actually involve moving the files to a new location but rather changing a record in the file system.

To move a directory on Windows:

```
if(!MoveFileW(L"C:\\Path\\OldDirName", L"C:\\Path\\NewDirName"))
{
     // Operation failed
}
```

On *nix:

```
if(rename("/path/olddirname", "/path/newdirname") != 0)
{
    // Operation failed
}
```

Wrapper macros:

```
#ifdef __linux__
#define MvDir(old, new) (rename((old), (new)) != 0)
#elif defined(WINVER)
#define MvDir(old, new) !(MoveFileW((L ## old), (L ## new)))
#endif
```

This also automatically wraps the success-test of the expression into a `1`/`0` value for you.

Answer (score 0):

> ...how to change the directory name? ...All I found was `rename()` that was changing filenames.

No, that's incorrect.  `rename` is totally fine for renaming directories, also.

> Linux uses `mv` command for renaming a directory but if the directory contains large files then moving will take time more right?

The `mv` command is typically implemented using `rename`, which is very fast.  Renaming a directory does not necessarily require moving (or doing anything with) the files in it.

If you're doing a more complicated rename, like trying to rename `a/b/c` to `d/e/f`, and if this ends up trying to move things onto a different mounted filesystem, then a simple directory rename won't work, and yes, actually "moving" (actually copying) of files would be required.  In that case, the `rename()` call will fail, so you'll know.  (`errno` should contain `EXDEV`.)

In the cross-device case, the `mv` command will do the expensive work of copying files, but only if it has to.

If you use `rename` from a C program, you'll get a quick rename for renames on the same filesystem, and an error for renames that attempt to cross filesystems, and you'll never get any expensive copies unless you code them up yourself.